# Dynamodb unmarshal map into struct

Tags: go, struct, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go

I am trying to retrieve a column from dynamodb which is saved as `map[string][]string` (map with key as string and values as a list of string)

example:

```
{ 
  { "string1": ["1", "2"]},
  { "string2": ["3", "4"]},
}
```

I am getting the data but I am not able to unmarshal it and store it in the struct

```
type Record struct {
    listOfMap map[string][]string
}

scanInput := &dynamodb.ScanInput{
    TableName:            aws.String("someTable"),
    ProjectionExpression: aws.String("desiredColumnToRetrieve"),
}

dynamodbOutput, err := svc.dynamodb.Scan(scanInput)
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("dynamodb.Scan() error - %s", err)
}

fmt.Println(dynamodbOutput)

records := []Record{}

err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalListOfMaps(dynamodbOutput.Items, &records)
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalListOfMaps() error - %s", err)
}

fmt.Println(records)
```

dynamodb output (this output is from the above print statements):

```
{
  Count: 2,
  Items: [{
      desiredColumnToRetrieve: {
        M: {
          string1: {
            L: [{
                S: "1"
              },{
                S: "2"
              }]
          }
        }
      }
    },{
      desiredColumnToRetrieve: {
        M: {
          string2: {
            L: [{
                S: "3"
              },{
                S: "4"
              }]
          }
        }
      }
    }],
  ScannedCount: 2
}
{[map[] map[]}
```

The data is not getting saved to the struct/map

Answer (score 0):

Probably it would not work, you need to iterate over items first, like:

```
for _, i := range dynamodbOutput.Items {
        record := Record{}

        err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(i, &record)
```

And in fact, your listOfMaps is regular map. Why do you call so? It's rather mapOfLists

By the way doing full scans on NoSQL tables isn't the best practice, if you are going to do always, you'd better to review partitioning sorting keys and whole data schema. Cheers.

Comment: thank you for the reply but its not working. 
I have a list of map with key as string and values as a list of string
example: { 
  { "string1": ["1", "2"]},
  { "string2": ["3", "4"]},
}

so I thought I would need UnmarshalListofMaps

Comment: err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalListOfMaps(dynamodbOutput.Items, &records) would NEVER work. You need to iterate over dynamodbOutput.Items if for loop, and then unmarshal AttributeValue, which is value of Item element into your Record, there is no other way

Comment: for _, i := range dynamodbOutput.Items { do this first, and then unmarshal i

Comment: what I really think is I am not initializing the map so the output is an empty map.
Is there a way to initialize a struct which contains map?

Comment: are you kidding me? do you have debugger? I am doing this stuff everyday with dynamodb. ITERATE OVER ITEMS inside of for loop first! dynamoattribute can unmarshal only dynamodb related stuff, not regular lists. This is mistake

Comment: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/go/example_code/dynamodb/scan_items.go